# Process Exited event handler method is not being called

Tags: c#, .net

Here is the following code...the `Process.Exited` event handler method is not being called...I also checked that by breakpoints and all of that.

```
Process f;

private void button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f = new Process();
    f.StartInfo.FileName = "tutorial.mp4";
    f.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    f.Exited += new EventHandler(f_Exited);
    f.Start();
}

private void f_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //some stuff not important
}
```

Comment: Is the process actually exiting? You seem to be playing an .mp4 file. Normally, Windows will start up some media player to do this, but after that it's usually up to the user to close the media player application. The process won't exit automatically just because it's finished playing the file.

Comment: wether it has exited manually or automatically shouldnt that pass it to the exit method?

Comment: Yes. But if it doesn't exit at all, you'll never see that event. Why would the process exit? Are you closing the media player? Also, I haven't checked but I'm not entirely certain that when you start a process in this way (i.e. use Windows Shell to start a program based on a file association) that the `Process` object is even actually tied to that process. You should double-check the `Process` object after you start it to make sure it is. Obviously you won't get the event if the `Process` object isn't attached to an actual process.

Comment: yup mate the process is exiting.. its just a 10 seconds video..

Comment: didnt understand the double check part...can u please say it clearer,,,thx in advance

Comment: You need to add `f.StartInfo.Verb = "open";` to get the Exited event to fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this isn't possible, because it isn't guaranteed that a process is started at all when you open a file like this.

Suppose there isn't any standard program set for the file type ".mp4". Then Windows will ask the user to choose a program to open the file; but if the user cancels this and do not choose a program at all, then no process is started. Therfore I believe that in such a case the Exited event isn't fired at all because you can not rely on this.

All i can think of is to start the player directly with an appropriate command line argument, like so:

```
Process f;
private void  button3_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    f = new Process();
    f.StartInfo.FileName = "wmplayer.exe"; // or something other
    f.StartInfo.Arguments = @"c:\tutorial.exe"; // as for the wmplayer, you have to specify the whole path.
    f.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    f.Exited += new EventHandler(f_Exited);
    f.Start();

}
private void f_Exited(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //some stuff not important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just checked. When you use `Process` in this way, it *does not* attach the `Process` object to an actual process. For example, if you try to call `Process.WaitForExit()`, you will get an exception. So of course the `Exited` event can't be raised either; the `Process` object has no way to know what process even started, never mind when it exits.

If you want to do this, you either need to start the actual media player, providing the necessary command-line argument or DDE verb to it to play the specific file, or you will need to search the existing processes after you start the process, looking for the one that you believe to be the process that just started.

Note that only the former option is reliable. It is theoretically possible in the latter case that you might find some other instance of the media player (depending on which media player you are using and whether it can operate as multiple instances).